# sudo python3 not working to gain root acces

Tags: python-3.7

Hi so im trying to run root on a program im doing to run some neopixles and when I try running it it comes up with the error

```
File "work.py", line 1
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jan 22 2021, 20:04:44) 
         ^
```

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

I am pretty new to this so I don't really know whats wrong any thoughts why this is happening?
https://learn.adafruit.com/neopixels-on-raspberry-pi/python-usage

Comment: Is your code _syntactically_ correct?

Comment: What do you mean sytactically?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.